# Probability density for isobaric-isothermal ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am trying to find out what the probability density is for the isobaric-isothermal ensemble. I have been told that the partition function is given by
$$ Z(T,P) = \int_0^\infty d V e^{- \beta P V} Z_{\operatorname{can}} (T,V) \ .$$
Our textbook does not have a reference on this particular ensemble, so this is all I have to go on. From the above it is not obvious to me what the probability density should be, in particular I cannot quite grasp what the partition function is describing.

Typically, one would derive the probability density by maximizing Gibbs entropy, subject to some constraints, with respect to the probability density as a functional, but I am unable to get the desired result doing this. I need to calculate the expected energy of the system, but without the probability density this does not seem possible. My intuition says that the average energy should be something along the lines of
$$ E(T,P) = \int_0^\infty e^{- \beta P V} E_{\operatorname{can}}(T,V) \ .$$

Answer (score 1):

$Z_\mathrm{can}$ is the partition function for the canonical ensemble, i.e. constant NVT. If instead of a constant $V$ you have a constant $P$ then you perform a weighted sum over the NVT configurations for every V, where the contributions are weighted in accordance with the probability of that particular volume occurring. The energy of a volume $V$ at pressure $P$ is $PV$, so the appropriate weight is the Boltzmann factor $\exp(-\beta PV)$.